# What types of questions should I be expecting for my final year project viva for my undergrad?

Tags: computer-science, university, defense

Currently doing a final year project in artificial intelligence and was curious to know how this presentation(viva) works ? and how I should prepare for it ? are there common questions I should prepare for ? Do I have to explain my code?

Answer (score 4):

**Ask your supervisor**: Vivas vary between institutes.

Comment: Is there something general they ask ?

Comment: @Jack Institutes may each have some generic questions, but they'll vary between institutes.